# Detecting broken hyperlinks with ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, hyperlink

I have zero experience with python but am trying to search for broken hyperlinks in a large gdb (temporarily converted to a shapefile)-

Used code from a previous question ([Using ArcPy to verify paths of Hyperlinks?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76900/hyperlink-broken-path-python-check)) and adapted it to fit my problem (didn't know if I could ask a new question on that post...)

```
import arcpy
import os

fc = r"G:\GISDATA\misc\project_arcpy.shp"
fields = ["PROJECT_DW"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc,fields) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    Roll = str(row[0])
    if os.path.exists(Roll):
        pass
    else:
        f = open(r"C:\Users\GIS\Documents\brokenlinks.txt","a")
        f.write(Roll + os.linesep)
        f.close()
```

Instead of writing broken hyperlinks to my text file, it writes all they hyperlinks to the file.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what defines a broken hyperlink?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Either way I think the key will be to use a Search Cursor to look up where the Hyperlink field is pointing and then use `arcpy.Exists()` to see if that location exists.

Comment: Broken hyperlink= hyprelink won't work anymore because the name was changed by a coworker or the document no longer exists.

Comment: PolyGeo=using arcgis 10.1. OK, thanks...I will try to put that into code..

Comment: @Tracy: Is the field "PROJECT_DW" contains web link or network/local disk path or both?

Comment: It was a network path- I actually ended up importing the table into excel and finding broken links that way

Comment: `os.path.exists()` will work with absolute paths or relative paths (to the current working directory), so the paths stored in `PROJECT_DW` will matter.  Are they absolute or relative?