# Detecting broken hyperlinks using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, hyperlink

I am trying to use ArcGIS 10.2.2 to detect broken hyperlinks from a .shp and export them to a text file.

Is this possible to do this with Python scripting?

I only want to see the broken hyperlinks in the text file.

I tried using the script from [Using ArcPy to verify paths of Hyperlinks?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76900/hyperlink-broken-path-python-check), but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did or didn't work for you with that other script? It's hard for others to offer suggestions if they don't have any idea what didn't work.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but we'll need to see a snippet from your code and the error that it produces before your question can become answerable.